# React refactor componentDidMount() to call function

Tags: reactjs, components, axios

I have a working componentDidMount component using axios that's starting to have redundant calls.

I've tried to make a separate function to call but now it's breaking everything.

I've tried reordering the functions and where they're declared... but when trying to render I'm getting null errors.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

#### Working Component

```
componentDidMount() {
    const url = `${API_URL}?$limit=${API_LIMIT}`;
    const record_count = `${API_URL}?$select=count(*)`;
    axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ meteorite: data })
        console.log(this.state.meteorite)
      })
    axios.get(record_count).then(response => response.data)
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ total_count: data }) 
        console.log(this.state.total_count)
      })  


  }
```

#### Attempting...

```
getData(url){  
    axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)
      .then((data) => {
        return data;
      })
  }

componentDidMount() {
    const init_url = `${API_URL}?$limit=${API_LIMIT}`;
    const record_count_url = `${API_URL}?$select=count(*)`;
    console.log("init_url: " + init_url)
    this.setState({ meteorite: this.getData(init_url) })
    this.setState({ total_count: this.getData(record_count_url) })

  }
```

Comment: I think you should not do async operation in setState, I dont have good reasoning but I think it may not work appropriate inside setState as setState itself is async and then you are calling a function that returns promise which will be set as the value instead of the real value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the refactored version.

```js
getData = (url, key) => {
  axios.get(url)
    .then(response => response.data)
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        [key]: data
      })
    })
}

componentDidMount() {
  const url = `${API_URL}?$limit=${API_LIMIT}`;
  const record_count = `${API_URL}?$select=count(*)`;
  this.getData(url, 'meteorite');
  this.getData(record_count, 'total_count');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're really close, you just need to return the axios call and put setState inside a then to capture the data.

```
getData(url) {
  return axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)
    .then((data) => data)
}

componentDidMount() {
  const init_url = `${API_URL}?$limit=${API_LIMIT}`;
  const record_count_url = `${API_URL}?$select=count(*)`;
  console.log("init_url: " + init_url)
  this.getData(init_url).then(meteorite => this.setState({ meteorite }))
  this.getData(record_count_url).then(total_count => this.setState({ total_count }))
}
```

I've use a bit of object destructuring in the then statements to keep the code more concise.